# Need Help on Filtering Duplicates from two multidimensional arrays then create array of only unique

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying filter and remove Duplicate value from array and Add new ones to the table. i tried using the following code. I have been working on this for hours Please help!

```
$tmpArray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $duplicate = false;
     foreach($recordd as $data2) {
     if($row['SalesDescription'] === $data2['fields']['WO Notes'] ) $duplicate = true;
     }

    if($duplicate === false)
       $tableId = 50240233993;
       $tmpArray = $row;

    $records=array(
      'SO Qty' => 'Test',
      'WO Qty'          => $tmpArray['Reference'],
      'SO Date'          => $tmpArray['TransactionDate'],
      'Color'         => $tmpArray['DistNumber'], 
      'SO#'         => $tmpArray['Reference'], 
      'Promised Date'         => $tmpArray['ItemId'], 
      'WO Notes'         => $tmpArray['SalesDescription'], 

   );


  $tv->addRecord($tableId, $records);// call to addRecord() function which adds data to Cloud table
 }
```

Here is the Old record

```
Array ( 
  [id] => 56554535376 
  [table_id] => 50240233993 
  [created] => 2014-10-30T09:52:15-0600 
  [updated] => 2014-10-30T09:52:15-0600 
  [created_by] => 3045444045538 
  [fields] => Array ( 
                    [Work Order] => 87565 
                    [SalesDescription] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFT TIRE PRESS-ONS 
                    [SO#] => 14061 
                    [SO Date] => 2013-10-16T00:00:00-0600 
                    [Promised Date] => 2014-10-30T09:52:15-0600 
                    [SO Qty] => 1.0000000000000000000 
                    [WO Qty] => 14061 
                    [Color] => 2 
                    [s] => 2 
                    [SHIP BY] => 2014-10-29 
                    [CALC PROMISED DATE] => 2014-10-30 
                    )
```

)

Here is the new record looks like

```
 Array ( 
   [0] => CAS001 
   [CustomerId] => CAS001 
   [1] => CASH CUSTOMER 
   [Customer_Bill_Name] => CASH CUSTOMER 
   [2] => Will Call 
   [WhichShipVia] => Will Call 
   [3] => [INV_POSOOrderNumber] => [4] => 2013-07-24 
   [ShipByDate] => 2013-07-24 
   [5] => [GoodThruDate] => [6] => [CustomerSONo] => [7] => 13867 
   [Reference] => 13867 [8] => 2013-07-24 
   [TransactionDate] => 2013-07-24 
   [9] => 1 
   [DistNumber] => 1 
   [10] => 2.0000000000000000000 
   [Quantity] => 2.0000000000000000000 
   [11] => 121130581 
   [ItemId] => 121130581 
   [12] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFT TIRE PRESS-ONS 
   [SalesDescription] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFT TIRE PRESS-ONS 
   [13] => [PartNumber] => [14] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFTTIRE 
   [ItemDescription] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFTTIRE
   )
```

Comment: Try this 
    if($duplicate === false){ ... stuff to do ...}  not 
    if($duplicate === false) "no brace"

Comment: So, there's a couple things here. First, you can remember that PHP "arrays" are really just hash-array hybrids, and create an O(1) lookup array of already seen values (that can be checked against). Second, Did you mean for `if ($duplicate === false)` to only set `$tableId = 50240233993` but everything else to continue as normal?

Comment: @mr.stobbe Correct `if ($duplicate === false)` then add unique record to  `$tableId = 50240233993`,  this line `$tv->addRecord($tableId, $records)` calls to the function which takes `tableID` and `$records` and adds record to the table.

Comment: @Kuku - see my answer, you have a logic error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I put in my comment you are missing a `{  }` block.  To fully explain:

```
if($duplicate === false) ///<-- no brace
   $tableId = 50240233993;
   $tmpArray = $row;  //<-- this will execute no matter the value of $duplicate

$records=array(
  'SO Qty' => 'Test',
  'WO Qty'          => $tmpArray['Reference'],
  'SO Date'          => $tmpArray['TransactionDate'],
  'Color'         => $tmpArray['DistNumber'], 
  'SO#'         => $tmpArray['Reference'], 
  'Promised Date'         => $tmpArray['ItemId'], 
  'WO Notes'         => $tmpArray['SalesDescription'], 

 );


 $tv->addRecord($tableId, $records);// call t...
```

Essentially what you have above is this

```
if($duplicate === false){
   $tableId = 50240233993;
}
$tmpArray = $row;  //<-- this will execute no matter the value of $duplicate
....
```

Your just telling php to set the id if its not a duplicate then the rest executes because its not wrapped in  braces,  try this

```
if($duplicate === false){
        $tableId = 50240233993;
        $tmpArray = $row;

     $records=array(
       'SO Qty' => 'Test',
       'WO Qty'          => $tmpArray['Reference'],
       'SO Date'          => $tmpArray['TransactionDate'],
       'Color'         => $tmpArray['DistNumber'], 
       'SO#'         => $tmpArray['Reference'], 
       'Promised Date'         => $tmpArray['ItemId'], 
       'WO Notes'         => $tmpArray['SalesDescription'], 

     );


      $tv->addRecord($tableId, $records);// call t
}
```